# Problems with JavaScript Promises and an API

Tags: javascript, promise

Good day. I need to popluate a table from an external API and mostof the info I can get from 1 request however I need a second request to populate the developer column. However my promise function does not populate the table for some reason. Please tell me if I am doing something wrong.
The string **devList** is supposed to be put into the innerHTML of document.getElementById(curDev).

```
const req1=new XMLHttpRequest();
const rawgAPIkey="*******************"; //real key used here
const baseurl="https://api.rawg.io/api";
const url=new URL(baseurl+"/games");
var tbl=document.getElementById("gametable");
url.searchParams.set("key", rawgAPIkey);
req1.open("GET", url);
req1.responseType="text";
req1.send();
req1.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(req1.readyState===4 && req1.status===200){
        var gameArr = JSON.parse(req1.responseText).results;
        console.log(JSON.parse(req1.responseText).results);
        for (let index = 0; index < gameArr.length; index++) {
            var game;
            
            let genres="";
            let tempGenre=gameArr[index].genres;
            for (let index4 = 0; index4 < tempGenre.length; index4++) {
                genres += tempGenre[index4].name;
                if(index4!=tempGenre.length-1){
                    genres+= ", ";
                }
            }
            
            let platforms="";
            let tempPlatforms=gameArr[index].platforms;
            for (let index2 = 0; index2 < tempPlatforms.length; index2++) {
                platforms += tempPlatforms[index2].platform.name;
                if(index2!=tempPlatforms.length-1){
                    platforms+=", ";
                }
            }

            let Tags="";
            let tempTags=gameArr[index].tags;
            for (let index3 = 0; index3 < 3; index3++) {
                Tags += tempTags[index3].name;
                if(index3!=2){
                    Tags+=", ";
                }
            }
            let agerating="";
            if(gameArr[index].esrb_rating!=null){
                agerating=gameArr[index].esrb_rating.name;
            }else{
                agerating="Rating unavailiable";
            }

            tbl.innerHTML+=
            "<tr>"
            +" <td> " + " <p> " + gameArr[index].name +  " </p> "
            + "<img class=\"gamepic\" src=\" "+ gameArr[index].background_image + " \" alt=\"CS:GO\">" + " </td> "
            + "<td id=\"developerID" + index + "\">" + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + gameArr[index].released + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + genres + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + agerating + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + platforms + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + Tags + "</td>";

            let curDev="developerID"+index;
            var url2=new URL(baseurl+"/games/"+gameArr[index].id);
            url2.searchParams.set("key", rawgAPIkey);
            var developer="";
            async function getDev(){
                let myProm= new Promise (function(success, fail){
                    const req2= new XMLHttpRequest();
                    req2.open("GET", url2);
                    req2.responseType="text";
                    
                    req2.onload=function(){
                        if(req2.status===200){
                            var gamedevs=JSON.parse(req2.responseText).developers;
                            devList="";
                            for (let i = 0; i < gamedevs.length; i++) {
                                devList += gamedevs[i].name + " ";
                            }
                            success(devList);
                        }else{
                            fail("Developer unavailable");
                        } 
                    };
                    req2.send(); 
                });
                document.getElementById(curDev).innerHTML= await myProm;
            }
            getDev();
        }
    } 
}
```

EDIT 2:
Got it working by doing the following where I just populated the table in the same function where I set devList thus I am not using promises anymore:

```
async function popdevs(){
                let req2= new XMLHttpRequest();
                req2.open("GET", url2);
                req2.responseType="text";
                req2.onload=function(){
                    if(req2.status===200){
                        var gamedevs=JSON.parse(req2.responseText).developers;
                        devList="";
                        for (let i = 0; i < gamedevs.length; i++) {
                            devList += gamedevs[i].name + " ";
                        }
                        document.getElementById(curDev).innerHTML= devList;
                        //console.log(devList);
                        //success(devList);
                        return devList;
                    }else{
                        //console.log("Hello");
                        return "developer unavailable";
                    } 
                    };
                    req2.send();
            }
            popdevs();
```

Comment: Why are you calling `success(devList)`?

Comment: @NicolásLonghi I am working from what I get on https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_async.asp I do not completely understand promises though so I might be wrong. Thus any changes will be appreciated.

Comment: Should work this way. Looks like you need to debug this on your own or create a [mre], otherwise we can't help much

Comment: I see you got it to work. Very good! I recommend you do some training on promises and learn about them since, not only they are very helpful, but they are widely used so you will run into them in the future. You may find a lot of material about this on the web. Just to mention one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QO4NXhWo_NM